# for loop not returning value in list after matching the expression

Tags: scala, for-loop, match, yield

I have used match expression  using yield in for loop but I am not getting desired result

```
   val daysOfWeek = List("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun")
        val day = "Mon"
         for (day <- daysOfWeek) yield
        {
          day match 
          {
            case "Mon" => "is boring"
            case otherDay => otherDay
              print(day)
          }
}
```

O/p of the above code is (TuesWedThurFriSatSun) but I want o/p like (is boringTuesWedThurFriSatSun)

How Can I achieve this ?

Comment: I think your problem is that the `print` is only executing in the case of other days. And also it is breaking the return type of all the expression to `Any`. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are printing within the otherday case block, so you get that as output.

Here is what you want to achieve:

```
 val daysOfWeek = List("Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun")
 val day = "Mon"
 for (day <- daysOfWeek) yield
 {
     val output = day match
     {
        case "Mon" => "is boring"
        case otherDay => otherDay
     }
     print(output)
 }
```

Output:

```
is boringTuesWedThurFriSatSun
```

Comment: If you are `yielding` an **Unit**. It would be better yo just use the `foreach` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Consider factoring out pattern matching into its own function

```
val boringDay: String => String = {
  case "Mon" => "is boring"
  case otherDay => otherDay
}
```

which can be used to transform the list

```
daysOfWeek.map(boringDay) // List(is boring, Tues, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun)
```

and now use `mkString` to get a printable string

```
val output = daysOfWeek.map(boringDay).mkString("")
println(output)
```

which outputs

```
res1: String = is boringTuesWedThurFriSatSun
```